# List<Map<String, String>> contains all elements from String[]. How to check it?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need to check that  `List<Map<String, String>>` contains all elements from `String[]`.

I solved this problem like this:

```java
    private boolean method(List<Map<String, String>> listWithMaps, String[] conditions){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map<String, String> mapFromList : listWithMaps) {
            list.add(mapFromList.get("CAUSE"));
        }
        return list.containsAll(Arrays.asList(conditions));
    }
```

But maybe there is a more correct way to solve my problem?

Comment: "More correct" as in you're encountering an issue with your solution?

Comment: Reminds me of an interesting tweet: "_When struggling to get the brackets right in List<Map<String, List<String>>>, it´s not a problem with generics or the language, but rather a hint for weak modeling._" (from @gunnarmorling)

Comment: Your example is correct. What do you mean by "more" ?

Comment: I mean the style of the code. Perhaps there is some kind of function in the collections that could be used in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of possibilities with streams:

```
listWithMaps.stream().map(map -> map.get("CAUSE")).collect(toSet()).containsAll(Arrays.asList(conditions));
```

and

```
Arrays.stream(conditions)
            .allMatch(condition -> listWithMaps.stream().anyMatch(map -> map.get("CAUSE").equals(condition)));
```